# Como capturar linha específica de textarea em JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web, textarea, markdown

- Gostaria de saber como capturar uma *linha específica* onde exista *determinada ocorrência* baseado no resultado de um textarea.
- A ideia é possibilitar uma marcação personalizada no mesmo sentido de um [markdown](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), mas com marcações personalizadas.
- Por exemplo, se meu JS estiver esperando pra converter uma linha iniciada por "## " em uma tag h2 do html, qual é o melhor jeito para identificar *toda* a linha(e apenas ela) e fechar a tag ao final?
- Gostaria de saber a maneira mais ágil pro navegador, apenas com Vanilla JS se possível, mas não descarto o uso de jquery e outros frameworks se necessário.

Comment: Você deve incluir um exemplo verificável do que você já conseguiu fazer. E eu gostaria de saber qual é seu intuito, porque me parece apenas uma reinvenção da roda.

Comment: Existem efectivamente alguns editores JS open source que poderá utilizar para integrar numa aplicação, como https://simplemde.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pretende tem várias etapas:

1. Obter o texto introduzido na `textarea`, e convertê-lo num `array`, onde cada entrada corresponderá a uma linha do texto na 'textarea'.
2. Pesquisar o conteúdo do array para localizar, por exemplo, uma linha iniciada com `##`.
3. Devolver o resultado em html (converter a linha iniciada com `##` numa tag `h2` válida.

Exemplo com jQuery e Expressões Regulares:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Neste exemplo são validadas as tags `<h1>` e `<h2>` e as restantes linhas são convertidas em parágrafos `<p>`.

```js
// Assegura que o documento html está totalmente carregado
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    // Clicando no botão executa a conversão  
    $('#botao-converter').click(function() {
      
      // Obtém o conteúdo do textarea e divide-o em linhas
      var arrayDeLinhas = $('#editor').val().split('\n');            
      
      var resultadoHTML = '';
      // Loop para validar e converter o conteúdo para html
      for (var i=0; i<arrayDeLinhas.length; i++) {
        var linha = arrayDeLinhas[i];
        var elementoEncontrado;
        // Expressões regulares para validar as linhas        
        var existeH1 = linha.match(/^#\s(.*)/);
        var existeH2 = linha.match(/^##\s(.*)/);
        
        if (existeH1) { elementoEncontrado = 'h1'; }
        if (existeH2) { elementoEncontrado = 'h2'; }
        
        switch(elementoEncontrado) {
          case 'h1':
            resultadoHTML+= '<h1>' + linha.replace(/^#(.*)/,'') + '</h1>';
            break;
          case 'h2':
            resultadoHTML+= '<h2>' + linha.replace(/^##(.*)/,'') + '</h2>';
            break;
          default:
            resultadoHTML+= '<p>' + linha + '</p>';
        }
          
      }                       
      
      // Mostra o resultado
      $('#resultado').html(resultadoHTML);
      
    });
        
});
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace}
```

```html
<h3>EDITOR:</h3>
<form>
<textarea id="editor" rows="8" cols="80">Texto
Texto e mais texto
Mais texto ainda
## H2 aqui
Mais texto
# H1 aqui
Texto simples  
</textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="botao-converter" type="button">Converter para Markdown</button>
</form>
<br>
<h3>RESULTADO:</h3>
<div id="resultado">O resultado irá surgir aqui</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

):

Comment: Na verdade oque eu esperava era apenas    
`// Obtém o conteúdo do textarea e divide-o em linhas
      var arrayDeLinhas = $('#editor').val().split('\n');  `  
mas foi uma ótima resposta, obrigado.